# Same font, same safari on same Mac - different look

Tags: safari, font-size

Whe have 2 websites that supposed to have the same headen/nav.
On both there is the same style: Arial, 15px, bold. On the same machine (MAC) in Safari 5.1 one looks bolder than the other one.

Group of people is trying to figure out why, and no clue.

The client is picky about it.

Attached screenshot of what I'm talking about.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. On on of the websites, html tag had these css lines:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```